# Problems with getBBox in Raphaeljs if set contains empty sets

Tags: javascript, raphael

Say you have Raphael set1, containing:
- a rect (r1)
- a set of rects (set2)
- an empty set (set3).

In Raphael element.getBBox() will work fine for set2. But for set1 it will return NaN (for x2, y2, width and height - but not for x and y, which work fine). set1 does however have width and height, since it also contains r1 and set2.

set3.getBBox().y2 will return -Infinity.

I have coded a little function that helps me get the "real" getBBox() of a set that contains an empty set, but it is quite convoluted. I'm sure there are more straightforward ways of solving this but I don't know enough js. Also , there's probably a few problems with my code that I have not seen yet. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
function newBBox(e){
    function clean(s){
        for (var i=s.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if (isNaN(s[i].getBBox().y2)) s[i] = clean(s[i])
            else if (s[i].getBBox().y2 == -Infinity) s.exclude(s[i]);
            };
        return s;
        }
    if (!isNaN(e.getBBox().y2)) return e.getBBox();
    // if not ok, e must be a set that at some point contains an empty set. Lets find it, exclude it and return the getBBox for the new set
    return clean(e.clone()).getBBox(); // can´t use e because its a pointer to the original set and we'll be excluding things from the set
    }
```